# SSMS installing with Azure Data Studio setup failed error code(0x800B0111)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

While installing the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with Azure Data Studio Getting failed as per below error.

Error:-
Setup Failed
[image: error screenshot]
Version 18.12.1

The certificate was explicitly marked as untrusted by the user (0x800B0111). Also attached the screenshot for reference.

Installing on Server 2019 (64-bit) with admin privilege.

Tried to install the ssms application on server but getting error as per screenshot, also attached the screenshot.

Server Details.
Windows Server 2019 64-bit
Installing with admin credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please download a previous release of SSMS from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#previous-ssms-releases) and it should work with one of the previous releases.

You can also try the preview version of SSMS v19 from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms-19?view=sql-server-ver16).

Please detect and repair Windows corruption using the [SFC Tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e).

Comment: tried to install with v19, 18.9.1 and 18.9.2 also but it getting same error as per screenshot.

Comment: Please detect and repair Windows corruption using this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e

Comment: Thanks @Alberto Morillo as attached above url with help of that able to installed the app successfully,,  < sfc /scannow , Dism /online /Cleanup-Image /Checkhealth,  Dism /online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth > these 3 command used to fixed the issue

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted if you consider my suggestions helped you install successfully.